# Restarting systemd service of host from azure iot edge module

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

As the title indicates, is it possible to restart the systemd service of host from an iot edge module?

With the following command,I am able to do it inside docker container.

```
$ docker run -ti -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Is it possible to do the same thing inside azure iot edge module?

Answer (score 1):

We wouldn’t recommend customers doing this. Instead one should do this from the host with root privilege.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I am explicitly not judging whether what you actually want to do is a good idea.**

It is possible to mount local paths inside your Edge modules, just as you would do with regular docker containers. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-access-host-storage-from-module

I have not tried to mount the systemd path, but technically this should work.